# Android fingerprint to open app

Tags: android, fingerprint

I have added fingerprint recognition to gain access to my android app using the Google Sample found here http://developer.android.com/samples/FingerprintDialog/index.html.  Everything works as expected but I am just thinking that if someone has the phone and adds a new fingerprint then they gain access to the app.  How can I prevent this?  Do I need to register the fingerprints within the app and then check against those?

Comment: "How can I prevent this?" -- AFAIK, you don't. "Do I need to register the fingerprints within the app and then check against those?" -- AFAIK, that is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this but hopefully no one would be able to add a fingerprint to the phone that should not be able to access your application.

If you want fingerprint authentication to unlock the app for convenience but also allows to enter a password or PIN, then your can add an option in the settings of the app to let the user choose if they want to **Enable Unlock with Fingerprint's Registered on the Phone** or simply always type their password. (Default set to password only)